# Click event not executed

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

An `onmouseover` over a cell generates a div inside that cell. That div has an `onclick`, but this `onclick` is not executed. Here's some sample code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tb2kK/9/)

JavaScript:

```
var oldCell='';
function addDiv(cell){
    if(oldCell != ''){
        oldCell.innerHTML = '';
    }
    cell.innerHTML = "<div class='innerDiv' onclick='console.log(this.parentNode);'></div>";
    oldCell = cell;
}
```

HTML

```
<table border='1px solid black'>
    <tr>
        <td class='cell' onmouseover='addDiv(this)'></td>
        <td class='cell' onmouseover='addDiv(this)'></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class='cell' onmouseover='addDiv(this)'></td>
        <td class='cell' onmouseover='addDiv(this)'></td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

I've tried focusing on the div, but this does not wok either. I've also tried giving the cell the `onclick`, and then  focusing on the cell instead of the div, but this doesn't work in Chrome, does in Firefox though.

Comment: the onclick event worked fine for me, it printed the html of the parent node to the console.

Comment: It works for me too. (Firefox)

Comment: It did **not** work for me (Chrome-dev).

Comment: It does not work in neither Chrome nor Firefox here though. No errors, no print, no nothing...

Comment: Works for me in Firefox (12), not Chrome (19). Interestingly, even if you add a click event handler to the `td`, it does not get executed. This is most likely a bug.

Comment: The way I see it in chrome dev when we hover over the TD it creates the div.  But when we click we are still just clicking on the TD and not the DIV element so it's not firing the onclick event.

Comment: @wirey: I just edited my previous comment. I was thinking the same, but even if an event handler is added to the `td`, it does not get executed. See http://jsfiddle.net/Tb2kK/22/ (first cell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the mouseover event is creating a new object inside of it everytime the "mouseover" event is called. Clicking on the object fires a mouseover event, which is likely replacing the element and therefore making it impossible to call an onclick event.

My guess at the event list:
- Mouseover
- Mousedown -> Mouseover
- Object replaced.
- Mouseup (doesn't count as click, because a new object is receiving only mouse up)

---

Edit:

If your goal is to just create a mousehover effect then you should use CSS's hover keyword.

See this fiddle that does essentially what you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Tb2kK/27/

---

Edit: To do it similar to how you're doing it, you need to check if a div already exists. One way would be to assign an id: http://jsfiddle.net/mZdpN/

Comment: Your observation is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/Tb2kK/24/ The `mouseover` event is triggered on `mousedown`.

Comment: Weird thing is that when I focus on the cell, in ff it does execute the div onclick... but chrome still doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/Tb2kK/25/

Comment: @arbitter: Firefox even executed the handler without focussing (for me at least). The browsers use different engines, so what works in one browser does not have to work in the other. For example, there seems to be a bug in Chrome where changing the cursor type programmatically triggers the `mousemove` event as well.

Comment: Neat, who would have guessed. So just don't create the DIV if it already exists.

Comment: So how should I fix this? I've also tried giving the cell the onclick event, and focussing on the cell, yet Chrome still doesn't execute neither onclicks.

Comment: @arbitter: That primarily depends on what you want to achieve. So: What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: @Tom: Not really what I'm looking for. It has to be a div inside the cell. This div is only showed when hovered over the cell. When clicked, a certain function should be executed. This isn't necessarily on the div, could also be on the cell under it, but ofcourse the div is positioned over the cell. As told before, I've tried by putting the onclick on the cell, and focussing on the cell when hovered (and after creating the div), but thus far in Chrome no luck.

Answer (score 0):

replace your js with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oldCell = null;
    function addDiv(cell){
        if (oldCell != null){
            oldCell.innerHTML = '';
        }

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'innerDiv';
        div.onclick = function() {
            console.log(this.parentNode);
        };
        cell.appendChild(div);   
        oldCell = cell;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it works in FF for me just fine see http://jsfiddle.net/Tb2kK/23/ i am looking for chrome